# Sorting a Generic List

Tags: c#, list

I was reading a tutorial on sorting a list, and I ran into this line of code

```
myGenericList.Sort((x, y) => String.Compare(x.name, y.name));
```

Ive tried looking into this but I just dont understand this line. Can anyone explain to me exactly what is happening in this line?

Comment: I think you have a typo.  Shouldn't it be: `myGenericList.Sort((x, y) => String.Compare(x.name, y.name));`?

Answer (score 6):

You're creating an `anonymous` `function` here.

The `function` `Sort` takes an Action delegate in which two arguments `x` and `y` are supplied.
The implementation of the `function` follows the `=>` which is read as "goes to".
Then, `String.Compare(x.name, y.name)` is executed using the arguments provided.
The return value of `String.Compare` is the result of the function, which is also what is used in determining the sort order for the `List`

Comment: I think this should be noted as well: The result of the `String.Compare` is the return value of the function.  That result is what's used to sort the list.

Comment: More precisely, `Sort` takes _one_ argument, and that's a delegate. The delegate in question has the signature `(T x, T y)` (where `T` is the `T` from `List<T>`) and return type `int`. Se my answer for details.

Comment: So `x` and `y` are list items in myGenericList correct or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: Exactly, `x` and `y` are basically `left` and `right` side comparisons. So `x` is an item in your `List`, as well as `y`.

Comment: @ios85 I guess you can say that, yes. The type of `x` and `y` is the same as the type of the items in the `List<>`. It looks like that type (class or struct) has a member called `name` of type `string`. The QuickSort algorithm will try a lot of `x`s and `y`s from your list to see if `x` is greater (return `int` is positive) or less (return negative) than `y`. After a number of tests, it can conclude that the list is then sorted according to your `Comparison<>` (lambda arrow `=>`).

Answer (score 3):

There's an overload of `Sort` that takes a `Comparison<>` delegate. A lammbda expression is convertible to a matching delegate type, and that's why it works.

See the [MSDN documentation for Comparison<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) for details.

In the upcoming .NET4.5 (Visual Studio 2012) it will be possible to create an `IComparer<>` very easily from a `Comparison<>`. This is through a new static "factory" method `Comparer<>.Create`.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about that comparer factory.  I wish they would back port that to previous versions of the framework (as well as all the other should-have-been-available-from-the-beginning features throughout).

Comment: @JeffMercado Better late then never. It will be nice when you can make an `IComparer<Person>` just by saying: `var comp = Comparer<Person>.Create((p1, p2) => p1.Age.CompareTo(p2.Age))`. Until .NET4.0 you have to declare an entire new class. Se the [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh737198(v=vs.110).aspx) (but I guess you already found the doc yourself).

Answer (score 2):

It basically says: To sort 2 elements (x & y) in myGenericList, use String.Compare on property "name" of x & y.